# Fastest way to remove duplicate lines in very large .txt files

Tags: sorting, file, duplicates

What is the best way to remove duplicate lines from large .txt files like 1 GB and more ?

Because removing one-after-another duplicates is simple, we can turn this problem to just sorting file.

Assume, that **we can't load whole data to RAM**, because of it's size.

I'm just waiting to retreive all records from SQL table with one unique index field (I loaded file lines to table earlier) and wondering, does exists way to speed it up.

Comment: On what hardware? In any specific language?

Comment: Any kind languages, tools, OS, just idea. I used mysql because of it index and (propably) fast tree searching algorythm, so it did work for me, but i'm wondering there is faster solution.

Comment: If it's already in mysql, couldn't you just `SELECT DISTINCT`? Is this going to be a repeated process of a once-off?

Comment: select distinct will load query result to RAM. Also execution time of a query will be terrible (if it will work at all with so much data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). While you may get some false positives (though you can get arbitrarily close to 0% at the cost of more processing) it should be pretty fast as you don't need to compare or even do a log(n) search for each line you see.

Comment: With a bloom filter or other hash-functions you can find the possible duplicates and compare and remove later.